# A 'is' operator between two generic types in kotlin?

Tags: kotlin

I tried to write a code like below, However an error occurs.

```
class Foo<T>: where Comparable<T?> {
    fun <U> bar(u: U) : where Comparable<U?> {
        if (u is T?) {
            // do something
        } else {
            // do something
        }
    }
}
```

in an 'if' clause, an error occurs

"Cannot check for instance of erased type"

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: 1) You can't do it if you are working with generics. 2) You can potentially work with class variable and use functions such as `isInstance`. 3) Why do you need such code at all?

Comment: Kotlin suffers from [type erasure](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/generics.html#type-erasure) just like Java. This is possible with [reified type parameters](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/inline-functions.html#reified-type-parameters), but those can only be used with [inline functions](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/inline-functions.html#inline-functions). What are you actually trying to accomplish?

Comment: Is this the code you have: `class Foo<T>: where Comparable<T?>`? It is not compiling not because of generics.